# Probability of tossing a die

Tags: probability, statistics

My whole class is troubled by this problem. Can you help?

We toss a die 5 times. Find probability that outcome after 4th toss is less or equal than the last toss.

Comment: Do the first three tosses have any relevance?  It seems that you could ignore these.  You have then only 36 cases to consider and you do it by brute force and ignorance.

Comment: Or use symmetry, instead of brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_4$ be the outcome of 4th toss and $X_5$ the outcome of the 5th. $X_4$ and $X_5$ are independent random variables and you just want to know $P(X_4\le X_5)$. The results from other tosses are irrelevant.

You can describe the sample space as the possible pairs $(x_4,x_5)$, as the possible results, $(1,1), (2,1),..., (6,6)$. There are 36 possibilities, each with probability 
$$P(X_4=x_4\cap X_5=x_5)=P(X_4=x_4)P(X_5=x_5)=1/6\times  1/6 = 1/36$$
As the 36 possible pairs are mutually exclusive events, you can add the probabilities of the pairs $(x_4,x_5)$ that comply with the condition $x_4\le x_5$. For instance, $(1,2), (4,5), (6,6)$ comply and $(3,2), (5,1), (4,2)$ don't comply. Now just make the required computations to get the final result.